# How to solve this equation for y? $y^2+2yx-3x^2=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

How to solve this equation for y?

$$y^2+2yx-3x^2=0$$

I know how to factor the unknown y with the coefficients of the expression and it would be $(y+3)(y-1)$ but I don't remember how to work out x. Should work a kind of substitution method - indeed, I dealt already with this kind of task in the past but can't find it in my copybooks right now.

Comment: Apply the quadratic formula with $a = 1, b = 2x, c = -3x^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y^2+2yx-3x^2=y^2-yx+3yx-3x^2=y(y-x)+3x(y-x)=(y+3x)(y-x)$

Comment: found out by myself before your answer but thank you! Indeed, I was wasting a lot of time on it!:(

Comment: you could also treat $x$ (or $y$) as a constant and use the quadratic equation to get the roots $-3x,x$